# Adding raw bytes to post parameters using Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, post, httpclient

Is there a way to add raw bytes to the post parameters using Apache's HTTPClient? My motivation is to stream the raw bytes of a stream in a particular encoding and then test what happens to that data when it gets to the server.

edit: I noticed that Apache has a deprecated method to add to the request body using an inputstream, so I could feed this a ByteArrayInputStream, but is there anything better/ not deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You didn't specify, so I'm assuming you are using Apache HttpClient version 4.x)

I don't think you can "add" raw bytes to an normally create request's POST parameters.

However, it should be possible to create a `PostMethod` with an `HttpEntity` which consists of legitimate parameters, plus some incorrectly encoded stuff.  You may need to do the formatting and encoding of the content yourself, but you might be able to take a short cut by putting the valid parameters into a `UrlEncodedFormEntity`, and then using the `writeTo` method to extract the formatted/encoded version into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.  After you've hacked the content bytes, turn them into a `ByteArrayEntity` instance with the appropriate content type and encoding parameters.

It will be messy ...